# Won't transform it back from sym to numeric, please see script

Tags: matlab

Hi I need to calculate some vector expression, using sym and then transform the result into numeric. I need to transform the bottom of this script so it will do the symbolic to numeric transformation, I don't know how to do it, anything I try fails. I always hit an error. I need your help.

This script should do it:

```
syms  v1 v2 v3
syms v1x v1y v1z v2x v2y v2z v3x v3y v3z
syms x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3
syms i j k
%%Calcul
v1x = v1 * i ;
v1y = v1 * j ;
v1z = v1 * k ;
v2x = v2 * i ;
v2y = v2 * j ;
v2z = v2 * k ;
v3x = v3 * i ;
v3y = v3 * j ;
v3z = v3 * k ;
x_n = zeros(1,3);
y_n = zeros(1,3);
z_n = zeros(1,3);
disp( 'Introduceti punctele de aplicatie, unghiurile in [grade] si coordonatele in [m]:' );
for i=1:3
    x_n(i) = input([ 'x(' ,num2str(i), ') = ' ]);
    y_n(i) = input([ 'y(' ,num2str(i), ') = ' ]);
    z_n(i) = input([ 'z(' ,num2str(i), ') = ' ]);
end
axb = dot(v1,v2);
bxc = dot(v2,v3)
cxa = dot(v3,v1)
%axb, numeric
axb = subs(axb, [v1 v2]);
disp( 'Expresia are valoarea numerica:' );
axb = subs(axb, [i,j,k]))      
%%bxc, numeric
bxc = subs(bxc, [v2 v3], [v_n(2) v_n(3)]);
disp( 'Expresia  are valoarea numerica:' );
bxc = subs(bxc, [i,j,k])
%%cxa, numeric
cxa = subs(cxa, [v3 v1], [v_n(3) v_n(1)]);
disp( 'Expresia are valoarea numerica:' );
cxa = subs(cxa, [i,j,k])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not using the [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function correctly if you want to substitute in numeric values for symbolic variables. Let's look at a small bit of your code (it's always good to simplify when things aren't working as expected and it also makes asking questions easier):

```
syms v1 v2;
axb = dot(v1,v2); % Takes the dot product of the variable v1 with v2
axb = subs(axb, [v1 v2]); % Substitutes in v1 and v2 to produce [dot(v1,v2) dot(v2,v2)]
```

I don't think `[ v2*conj(v1), v2*conj(v2)]` is what you wanted out of the code snippet above, is it? And there's certainly no way to get a numeric result out of that. [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) won't work. By the way, when you say "numeric," in Matlab the assumption is that you mean a particualr datatype, i.e., a number in a numeric class. See [`isnumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html). You may only want a symbolic value - a string - as opposed to a symbolic expression that includes functions and variables.

To get "numeric" output, substitute in values

```
syms v1 v2;
axb = dot(v1,v2);
V1 = [1 2 3];                       % Doubles
V2 = [sym('pi') sym('exp(1)') 1/3]; % Or you can use symbolic values
axb = subs(axb,{v1,v2},{V1,V2});    % Gives [ pi, 2*exp(1), 1]
```

Nou you can use `double(axb)` (or `eval(axb)` if you really need to) to get floating point values or `vpa(axb)` to obtain symbolic numbers. [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) will return symbolic values of arbitrary precision.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from this page the answer is that you should use the `double` command:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/double.html

If that does not work, perhaps try `eval`.

Comment: Where & how should I use double? I've tried and it failed too.